# jQuery slideUp and slideDown problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my rails app I have the menu that have to be hidden if mouse was unmooved for 5 seconds. It works fine with .hide() and .show(), but with .slideDown() and .slideUp() it starts to sliding up very fast, than sliding down and so on. Is there another approach to them? 
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i = null;
$("#all").mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(i);
    $(this).css("cursor", "default");
    $("#menu").show();
    i = setTimeout('$("#menu").hide();$("#flash_notice").hide(); $(this).css("cursor", "none");', 5000);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    clearTimeout(i);
    $("#flash_notice").hide();
        $("#menu").hide();
    $(this).css("cursor", "none");

}); });
```

Another issue is with `$(this).css("cursor", "none");`, it's seems to be working, but from time to time, so I'm really confused, what should I do.
 Thank you in advance for any tip.
  Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try introducing a chained `.stop()` before `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`, which stops any previous animations and will animate from the current position.

Comment: any idea, why isn't working  `$(this).css("cursor", "none");`?

Comment: I don't think cursor:none is widely supported in browsers, so I doubt that will work consistently. How about using a css file instead of attaching this via javascript? My instant reaction would be "why has my cursor disappeared? Oh the application is crashing - close the window", so I'd steer clear of hiding the user's cursor if you are targeting the web.